# How to use C++ dlopen macro to load a library from C++ code instead from JAVA

Tags: java, android, c++, c, android-ndk

I'm trying to use some already written C++ code for server communication in my Android application (Basically creating a client), sadly, the logic of the code depends on this piece of code:

```cpp
#ifndef LoadLib
#define LoadLib(a) (hmod)dlopen(a, RTLD_NOW)
#endif
```

The code gets called from:

```cpp
m_hmod = LoadLib(m_namespace::LIBRARY);
```

where `LIBRARY = "nameofmylib.so"`

Problem is that when I call LoadLib, my m_var remains NULL, which means it can't find the library ( That's my guess so far ) and so my logic goes into error handling rather than connecting to the socket.

So far, I've been surfing StackOverflow and trying solutions people suggest with changing the Gradle file and adjusting CMakeList.txt but none work. I've been debugging it for few hours as well, and I even tried looking for the .so location inside the Android Studio Device File Explorer, so that I could put in the absolute path. But that also yielded no results.

The complete flow of loading goes like this:

```cpp
#ifndef LoadLib
#define LoadLib(a) (hmod)dlopen(a, RTLD_NOW)
#endif


typedef void * hmod;
hmod m_hmod;

m_hmod = LoadLib(m_namespace::LIBRARY);

if (m_hmod) {
    ... Some code that needs to execute ...
} else {
    ... What actually happens ...
}
```

The code I am working with isn't something I wrote, but I have to stick to it, thus I need to use the logic that's inside it rather than rewriting it and making my own.

Comment: Have you tried checking `dlerror` output when searching for the error? https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlerror

Comment: BTW, dlopen isn't a macro. Your title just tweaked my inner pedant, the one who gets me through my programming day, every day, because nobody is more pedantic than a computer.

Comment: @Kaldrr Yeah, it says: "dlopen failed: library \"nameofmylib.so\" not found"

Comment: @Omnifarious My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `m_namespace::LIBRARY` is not being packed into the APK. To check this, you don't need to examine the device files. Android Studio provides a menu command to analyze your APK.

If the library is missing, you should ask yourself if the name follows Android rules: it must begin with **lib** and it must end with **.so**. No number suffixes, no extra characters, and God forbid, no spaces.

If the library name is OK, but it is used prebuilt by your CMake script, check that it is available for the ABI of your device. Also, make sure that its path is listed in **jniLibs.src** list in **build.gradle**.

Comment: Does it have to be in a particular directory in the APK too?

Comment: Definitely. But there is very little chance you managed to put it in a wrong directory.

Comment: @AlexCohn Okay, I did the analyze part, found that my file wasn't included, fixed around stuff in Gradle and now it's included. Problem still persists tho. My `LoadLib` still returns `NULL`, so I'm thinking it might not be able to reference the file? Even tho it's there, is there any alternative to `dlopen`?

Comment: Please be more specific: can you post the list of contents of your APK, so that I see that the library *is* included as I would expect it to be

Comment: @AlexCohn Okay, so, I managed to change everything around the build and CMakeList so that it works and compiles. It was rather CMake that was the issue. Now the library is included, but I realized that it's not compiled for arm-architecture, thus it didn't run. I now have a hella lot more issue, but the one I asked here is resolved. Thanks!